# Bio scan fitness score

Tags: training

My recent bio scan gave me a fitness score of 71. How can I increase this in 6 weeks. I do 5 boot camp sessions per week. I weigh 67 kilos and 160 cams tall.
I need a training program to increase fitness score.

Comment: How is this 'score' measured?